# Ansible jumphost config

Tags: ssh, ansible

I've added a new host `k8s` in an existing inventory hosts.yml

```
...
k8s:
  hosts:
    <address>
...
```

And the thing that bugs me is that, when I try to test if I can reach the host:

```bsh
ansible k8s -m ping -i hosts.yml
```

it tries to use a jumphost , and I don't want to use the jump server, because I have access directly to the `k8s` machine . Any idea from where ansible takes automatically the jumphost ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible connection method for linux is **OpenSSH**.

So check if the jumphost is configured under **~/.ssh/config** or **/etc/ssh/ssh_config** and disable it.